# how to use loop to run through set of lists

Tags: r

I am trying to create an r loop to run a command on a series of datasets.  the command is `make.design.data` from the `RMark` library.  The only argument it takes is the name of a list.  I have 17 of these lists I'd like to pass to make.design.data  This is the code I've been trying to use

```
DFNames<-c("DFAmerican.Goldfinch", "DFAmerican.Robin","DFBarn.Swallow","DFBobolink",     "DFBrown.head.Cowbird", "DFCedar.Waxwing", "DFCommon.Grackle","DFCommon.Yellowthroat", "DFEuropean.Starling","DFHorned.Lark", "DFKilldeer","DFRed.wing.Blackbird", "DFSavannah.Sparrow", "DFSong.Sparrow","DFTree.Swallow", "DFVesper.Sparrow", "DFYellow.Warbler")

#in my environment each of the names given to DFNames represents a list

for (x in DFNames){
n<-make.design.data(x)
assign(paste0("ddl",x),n)
 }
```

this gives me the error

```
  Error in data$model : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

can anyone please suggest a way to fix my code, or a different way of tackling this?

Thanks, Jude

Answer (score 3):

Instead, you can make a `list` of the actual data sets instead of a vector of their names.

```
x <- list(DFAmerican.Goldfinch, ...)
```

Then you can use:

```
 lapply(x, make.design.data)`.
```

Or use `get` inside your for loop:

```
for (x in DFNames) {
  make.design.data(get(x))
}
```

The "R" way is the former using lists and the `apply` family.  Then you can avoid the gymnastics of `assign`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.  The lapply gave me the same error message as my original code, but the lopp you suggested works great.